# Why is logarithm slower in Rust than in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point, rust, microbenchmark, jmh

If I run these benchmarks in Rust:

```rust
#[bench]
fn bench_rnd(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let mut rng = rand::weak_rng();
    b.iter(|| rng.gen_range::<f64>(2.0, 100.0));
}

#[bench]
fn bench_ln(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let mut rng = rand::weak_rng();
    b.iter(|| rng.gen_range::<f64>(2.0, 100.0).ln());
}
```

The result is:

```
test tests::bench_ln             ... bench:        121 ns/iter (+/- 2)
test tests::bench_rnd            ... bench:          6 ns/iter (+/- 0)
```

121-6 = 115 ns per `ln` call.

But the same benchmark in Java:

```java
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public static class Rnd {
    final double x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(2, 100);
}

@Benchmark
public double testLog(Rnd rnd) {
    return Math.log(rnd.x);
}
```

Gives me:

```
Benchmark    Mode Cnt  Score  Error Units
Main.testLog avgt  20 31,555 ± 0,234 ns/op
```

The log is ~3.7 times slower (115/31) in Rust than in Java.

When I test the hypotenuse implementation (`hypot`), the implementation in Rust is 15.8 times faster than in Java.

Have I written bad benchmarks or it is a performance issue?

Responses to questions asked in comments:

1. "," is a decimal separator in my country.
2. I run Rust's benchmark using `cargo bench` which always runs in release mode.
3. The Java benchmark framework (JMH) creates a new object for every call, even though it's a `static` class and a `final` variable. If I add a random creation in the tested method, I get 43 ns/op.

Comment: Isnt java bad to use as benchmark basis? I mean java is nice but in some cases, it is too nice

Comment: You're probably benchmarking the random number generator more than the log function. Also, I believe that Rust just uses the system math library, so a pure call to `log` should be the same as what it is in C (no idea about Java).

Comment: Could you rerun the test using `RUSTFLAGS='-Ctarget-cpu=native' cargo bench`?

Comment: @SimonByrne if OP were accidentally benchmarking the RNG, wouldn't that be offset by the `bench_rnd` function which *only* tests the RNG? That's why OP subtracts the two Rust benchmark timings — to make a pure benchmark of the `ln` function. I'd agree that it should just be calling the system math library though.

Comment: I know nothing in java but are you sure that x is update ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer was [given by @kennytm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037547/why-is-logarithm-slower-in-rust-than-in-java#comment77055999_45037547):

```
export RUSTFLAGS='-Ctarget-cpu=native'
```

Fixes the problem. After that, the results are:

```
test tests::bench_ln              ... bench:          43 ns/iter (+/- 3)
test tests::bench_rnd             ... bench:           5 ns/iter (+/- 0)
```

I think 38 (± 3) is close enough to 31.555 (± 0.234).

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to provide the other half of the explanation since I don't know Rust. `Math.log` is annotated with `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` meaning that it will be replaced by a native CPU instruction for such an operation: think `Integer.bitCount` that would either do a lot of shifting or use a direct CPU instruction that does that much faster.

Having an extremely simple program like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(mathLn(20_000));
}

private static long mathLn(int x) {
    long result = 0L;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        result = result + ln(i);
    }
    return result;
}

private static final long ln(int x) {
    return (long) Math.log(x);
}
```

And running it with:

```
 java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions  
      -XX:+PrintInlining 
      -XX:+PrintIntrinsics 
      -XX:CICompilerCount=2 
      -XX:+PrintCompilation  
      package/Classname
```

It will generate a lot of lines, but one of them is:

```
 @ 2   java.lang.Math::log (5 bytes)   intrinsic
```

making this code extremely fast.

I don't really know when and how that happens in Rust though...

Comment: Since Rust is statically (or AOT, if you'd like) compiled, it has to know a single platform to compile to. By default, it will be kind of conservative (32-bit x86 code might target the 686 processor, for example). The `-Ctarget-cpu=native` flag tells the compiler to target the machine that the compiler is running on; this allows the compiler to use the full set of available instructions (like your `popcnt` example).